Why did Oppenheimer toss his glasses onto the corner of the wall?
In a chemistry lab, Oppenheimer is advised by Niels Bohr to go to Germany to
learn from Max Born. The scene then changes into a montage style with a series
of scenes set to classical music playing in the background. In one of these scenes,
Oppenheimer breaks his glasses and throws them onto a corner of the wall where
pieces of glass already exist:

Why did Oppenheimer toss his glasses onto the corner of the wall?

I've seen that as "where and how far do pieces go when something explodes?" and a metaphor to "where will the explosion stop (if it stops...) if we push the button?". Remember that it's was experimental, and some people feared that the explosion would not stop and destroy our world. But that's merely my opinion though...

@OldPadawan - There was a mild worry that that might be the case. They modelled it and found that it was vanishingly unlikely. The story has grown somewhat in the retelling

ie "the story was crap"  :)   the same sort of idiocy was said about the LHC

@Fattie It's only "idiocy" until it explains the Fermi paradox

@OldPadawan That comes abit later in the movie as Teller has had the idea that one could have a chain reaction with atmospheric nitrogen. Compton and Bethe then determined that would be a no with probability 1 - Ɛ. Phew! Also, no risk, no fun! More on this here and in the treatise Nuclear astrophysicists at war

The script elaborates somewhat. Oppenheimer is trying to "hear the music" of a hidden universe of rules. Smashing a glass to watch how it breaks, then doing it again and again would seem perfectly symbolic of concepts like Entropy (e.g. that systems become disordered over time) and what we would now call Chaos Theory.

SPARKS explode in WAVES, WAVES of FIRE CRASHING on a SHORE of
GLASS, FLYING OVER the MEDIEVAL SPIRES of Gottingen, I watch
BORN and BOHR and DIRAC, GALAXIES of PARTICLES DISPERSE and
REFORM, a CUBIST PAINTING transfixes the Young Me, an
ORCHESTRA plays STRAVINSKY, I read THE WASTE LAND, I WRITE
FURIOUSLY at a desk, I WRITE FURIOUSLY on a chalkboard, I
SMASH a glass, and ANOTHER, and ANOTHER, WATCHING the SHARDS
skid across the floor, CATCHING and REFRACTING LIGHT, I watch
RAINDROPS scintillate a PUDDLE, STREAM down a windowpane, I
disturb the surface of a sink full of WATER, watching RIPPLES
propagate and INTERFERE, I BOUNCE a ball against a corner of
my room, studying its trajectory..


Maybe I'm getting you mixed up with someone else, but what happened to your massive 700k-something reputation account on the other stack?

@FShrike - Phew. It's still there

Oh huh. Remarkable to build up a significant new account in just 9 months.

@FShrike - People value the same sort of answers here; well-reasoned and well-referenced. I make it a point not to add anything to a post that I can't back up.

I'm too lazy to write an answer but I thought of a Jewish Wedding: "After the bride has been given the ring, or at the end of the ceremony (depending on local custom), the groom breaks a glass, crushing it with his right foot. The origin of this custom is unknown, although many reasons have been given. The primary reason is that joy must always be tempered. This is based on two accounts in the Talmud of rabbis who, upon seeing that their son's wedding celebration was getting out of hand, broke a vessel ... to calm things down"
